# Read a text file as first argument ( via drag and drop)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a windows batch file that will read a fileset from any text file via drag and drop (not as an explicit file name)

explicitly specifying the text file works. this displays the contents of *list.txt* :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in (list.txt) do (
    echo "%%i"
)
pause
```

but trying to pass the *list.txt* as the first argument (as in  via drag and drop ) fails. This parses the *file.txt* as %%i, rather than reading its contents like above.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "file=%~1"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("%file%") do (
    echo "%%i"
)
pause
```

How can I get this to read *any* file?

Comment: Use the USEBACKQ option.  It is needed because you are putting quotes around your filename.

Comment: that works. wow, the windows help really sucks at explaining usebackq.

Comment: What do you mean.  It is stated plain as day for the **usebackq** option: **and allows the use of double quotes to quote file names in file-set.**

Comment: I guess I need to read more carefully :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Squash man's comment. USEBACKQ option is needed because there are quotes around the file name.

```
@echo off
set "file=%~1"
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%file%") do (
    echo "%%i"
)
pause
```

Comment: Note that you can accept even your own answer to close the question as it is solved...

Comment: gotta wait 20 hours according to the pop-up

Comment: Alright... Just a sidenote: for this piece of code, you do not need Delayed Expansion...